# How to compare Input value HTML in script

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Here is my code. Basically im doing HTML. I put an input for username and password. Now i want to compare the input and the specific value. We need to do in Script. SO my question is, what is the code at the button to compare the specific value and the User Input.The result will display the `database.html`

```
<h1> Key in</h1>   
<input type =" text" id=" name" ><br>     
<button onclick=getElementbyId('database.html')> Hi</button>
```

```js
function myFunction()
if name = "Danial"{              
    open database.html
}
```

Comment: It's seems that you have some issue to learn before you can start doing html. Such as [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [if else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). If specific thing is not clear, you can ask here.

Comment: Its a basic thing so no need to post as question just google tutorial and try that if you face problem with code definitely will get help from stack but for syntax or business logic idea nope

Comment: Can you help me with the code ? email me : mramiruladly@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type ="text" id="name" ><br>

    <button onclick=myFunction('database.html')> Hi</button>

    <script>
        function myFunction()
        if ($('#name') == "Danial"){

              open database.html
        }

</script>
```

Comment: What the answer here? It's poor answer please add more details, and write a valid code.

Comment: This code doesn't work because there is no property to check with. You only defined the `id` from the input wich have a `value` > `.val()`

Comment: <html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Key in</h1>
        
        <input type =" text" id=" name" ><br>
        
        <button onclick=getElementbyId('database.html')> Hi</button>
        
        <script>
            function myFunction()
            if name = "amirul"{
                   alert( "please!!!");
                   
            }
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: @mramiruladly what is your comment for? @C0dekid.php He didn't mentch that she need to use jQuery and he didn't explain how to `open database.html`